# CPP | std stream printing error

Tags: c++

I am currently programming an  int matrix in cpp.

I wanted to add a printing function that prints the numbers in the following way:

```
1 2 3
7 6 9    
19 23 9
```

(every 2 intergers are seperated with a space, in the end of the line no space).
so I wrote the following code:

```
std::ostream& IntMatrix::operator << (std::ostream& out) const
{
    for(int i = 0; i < this->num_row; i++)
    {
            int j;
            for(j = 0; j < this->num_col - 1; j++)
            {
                    out << this->mat[i][j] << " ";
            }
            out << this->mat[i][j] << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

which is in the file IntMatrix.cpp.
however, every time I try to compile the code, this is what happens:

```
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

What to do?

Comment: Use the global operator overload.

Comment: Regardless of that error, try implementing a free function `ostream& operator << (ostream&, const IntMatrix&)` rather than the member `ostream& IntMatrix::operator << (ostream&) const`: the member operator would have to be invoked as `matrix << std::cout`, which is … unusual, and probably not what you wanted. See also the [operator overloading FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1521179) for tips on implementing operators.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a class member function use an overload for the global namespace:

```
 std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const IntMatrix& m) {
 }
```

and declare that one as `friend` of `IntMatrix`.